# Using plugin outside of Wordpress pages

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins, lightbox

I am trying to use lightbox plus plugin for Wordpress which works fine for most of my site.

I have a php page which is used by a jQuery AJAX function to retrieve data in order to paginate a large result set back in wordpress. This page is not part of wordpress.

I have managed to get Wordpress functions to work fine in this php page by using:

```
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/home/love/public_html/dev/wp-blog-header.php');
require('/home/love/public_html/dev/wp-load.php');
```

However, in this page is an include, and within the included file is a link to an external sheet which is meant to be brought in with a lighbox:

```
<a class="" rel="lightbox" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/more-product-info?a=<?php echo $post->ID ?>">
  <div id="moreprodinfo">More Info</div>
  </a>
```

This method of retrieving information in a lighbox works ok on most parts of my site, but its just not working on the part that uses AJAX to retrieve the link to the lighbox page.

I assumed it was something to do with plugins not working when the page is not part of Wordpress, but all the Wordpress function have been working so why not plugins? Also my cufon plugin doesnt work on this ajax retrieved page either.

Is it becuase I am using .html javascript function to display the content retrieved by AJAX:

```
if(pageType == 'prizeHome'){
 loading_hide();
 $("#tab-prize-home #container").html(msg);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a common issue when using ajax to load html content :

You probably call lightbox and cufon when document is ready, which happens only once **before** your ajax call. You have to call again lightbox and cufon **after** your ajax call.

Comment: ok thanks :) with cufon its easy, you can just add cofon.replace after the call, but im not sure how to do it with lightbox plus plugin? Ive tried including rthe script in the plugin folder but that doesnt help... do you know how i can call the plugin after my ajax call?@

Comment: Lightbox plus plugin uses colorbox, take a look at http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox